# Parsing HL7 string to XML failing

Tags: javascript, regex, vi, mirth, hexdump

We use Mirth Connect to parse HL7 pathology flat files to MLLP.  Consistently we are seeing Mirth errors parsing a specific field in the raw data.  However, it is not clear what the error is.  This is the hex dump.  The important sequence is the "10.8":

```
00000400  59 20 43 4f 55 4e 54 20  31 5e 4c 7c 7c 20 3e 31  |Y COUNT 1^L|| >1|
00000410  30 10 38 20 43 46 55 2f  4c 7c 7c 7c 4e 0d 4f 42  |0.8 CFU/L|||N.OB|
```

This is the data viewed in vi (note the "^P")

```
^URINE COLONY COUNT 1^L|| >10^P8 CFU/L
```

And Mirth fails with a "Uni character Error"

The issues seems to be that the binary / ASCII data is being incorrectly read / interpreted - but I have no idea how or why.  Attempts to use regex to replace ^P fail - probably because regex operates at a binary level?

Comment: Have you noticed that "^" symbol is a component separator and cannot be used to code the power. If you need it in the text it must be \S\. This is the message sender responsibility to comply with the HL7v2 standard.

Comment: Interestingly in some clients "^P" which is 0x10 is read as '.' - which is correct